# React Simple Re-Rendering - setState is not re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I know there are a few questions out there exactly like this, but believe me none of them solved this problem. The main difference is that im tryng to update a nested component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Events from './Events.js'
import EventType from '../events/EventType.js'
import PropertiesPanelStyle from './css/PropertiesPanel.css';
import JointProperties from './properties/JointProperties.jsx';

export default class extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Properties",
      visible: false,
      display: undefined
    }
    Events.on(EventType.JOINT_CLICK, this.onJointClick.bind(this));
  }

  onJointClick(clickedJoint) {
    console.log("CLICKED ",clickedJoint);
    this.setState({
      display: <JointProperties joint={clickedJoint}/>,
      visible: true
    });
  }

  render () {

    if(!this.state.visible)
      return (<div></div>);

    return  (<div>
      <div id="properties">
        <strong>{this.state.name}</strong>
        <div id="propertiescontent" key={1}>
          { this.state.display }
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Whenever i click, i get a new joint as a parameter, and set the display to be the  JointProperties to display a that joint. Whenever i do the first click, it displays correctly, but whenever i do the second click, it still displays the first joint (and the constructor of the JointProperties component is not called again)

Depending on what i click i will get different rendering, at least that was my initial idea. But idk if what am i missing here :(

Comment: Could you please add `JointProperties ` part also

Comment: Oh i just figured it out, i needed the componentWillRecieveProps to update the state xD react is smart enuff to not rebuild the whole component xD

Comment: `componentWillRecieveProps` . sooner going to depricated

Comment: It should be said: it's really bad practice to put a component in state. There's almost always another way (I'm tempted to just say always).

Comment: My other component code:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KGJgBk6cWH/

What would be a good aproach here then ?